# Cronjob continuously reduces free disk space

Tags: .net-core, cron, rc, linux-disk-free

I have a .NET Core 3.0 Console App, running on a Ubuntu 18.04 server. There is a simple launcher script in my home folder, called `my-app.sh`:

```
cd /home/service/my-app
./My-App
```

I wanted to start the file after reboot, so I created a cronjob for the launcher script, using `crontab -e`:

```
@reboot /home/service/my-app.sh
```

After reboot, MyApp lauches perfectly fine. But, when calling `df` repeatedly, I noticed that the free disk space of `/` was continuously decreasing! I tried to find out which file it is, but `ncdu` did not show any difference over time. I am *not* writing a file in MyApp, i.e. the total size of `/home/service` does *not* increase. After about 10 minutes, the whole free space is gone, and MyApp is quit by the system.

When I cancel MyApp after reboot, I see that the "memory leak" is immediately stopped. But: When I restart MyApp manually, there is no memory leak any more.

Now I tried to remove the cronjob and added the launcher script to the `/etc/local.rc` file instead:

```
# Start MyApp
su service -c 'sh /home/service/my-app.sh' &
```

Again, it started perfectly fine after reboot, and there is also *no* memory leak any more.

I have no idea at all what could be the problem. There is no problem when starting manually or from `/etc/local.rc`, but just when starting from the cronjob. Any idea what could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

> **tl;dr** Avoid user interaction in the console app (e.g. ReadLine() waiting for a certain input).

Details: I found out what happened. Here is the last part of the C# code of my console application:

```
// App can be quit by keyboard input "exit"
while (true) {
    Console.WriteLine("Enter 'exit' to close MyApp.");
    if (Console.ReadLine() == "exit")
        break;
}
```

Using this code, I wanted to keep the program running until a user inputs `exit` or until this "service" is killed. Unfortunately, what happens, is that the program, started by Cron or by `/etc/rc.local` skips the `ReadLine()` and runs into an endless loop, messing up the memory (and maybe swap on hard drive) with an endless number of `Enter 'exit' to close MyApp.` lines.
While `/etc/rc.local` seems to free the memory continuously, the cronjob requires more and more memory. No idea why, just an observation!

The solution is simple. I removed the interaction and added the following harmless endless loop, waiting for the process to be killed:

```
// App can only be stopped by killing the process
Console.WriteLine("Started in service mode. To close MyApp, kill the process.");
while (true) {
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```